# Programs using an Asian font for context menus and title bars

Tags: windows-xp, fonts

The image here describes what I'm talking about. How can I change this font back to Segoe UI?

[image]

Windows XP on this computer is in Chinese by the way.

I tried regional and language settings and I tried flipping everything to English or United States but to no avail.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: I see only English on your picture, you may have attached a wrong one.

Comment: Are you able to change the default fonts via: Right Click on Desktop > Properties > Appearance tab > Click "Advanced" ?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Windows itself is in chinese. I have set chrome to english but the asian font remains.